# Typescript types behave diametrically opposite

Tags: typescript

Why ?

```
type x<T> = T extends 1 | 2 ? true : false;

let c1: x<1 | 2 | 3> = true

type y = 1 | 2 | 3 extends 1 | 2 ? true : false;

let c2: y = false
```

Both valid at TS playground .

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAHgPAFQHxQLxQVCNgQHYAmAzlAIxQA+UATFAPxTABOArtAFxQBmAhgDZEIAbgBQIvhGBQAxqU7xyVWlQDMKdMzZjQkKCDRlKNIyqw58xQ0vqNWHbv0GjxkmdU770vARCA)

Comment: `c1` is typed as `boolean`, so it accepts either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Look up "distributive conditional types". Your first example is distributive and your second isn't.

Comment: Thanks for all ! heart of matter was in "distributive conditional types" .

Comment: What is the intended error?